# nginx proxy_redirect websockets, not proxy

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, redirect

I have been able to successfully set up nginx as a load balancer to proxy websocket requests (with SSL), however, really I think I need to be able to redirect them.  My desired configuration is to have nginx sitting in front of a farm of websocket servers on different machines, and redirecting (not proxying) to them in round robin fashion.  I don't want to proxy, because then nginx just ends up opening two concurrent connections (inbound + outbound) on the load-balancer.  So even if my websocket farm can handle many concurrent connections per machine, the overall number of concurrent connections is limited by the load-balancer.  I want the client to end up with a direct connection to the websocket server that does not go through nginx.

I have looked for an example of someone else doing this, and have not found much that seems very relevant.  I think the directive I want to use is proxy_redirect, but, as mentioned, the documentation and other posts are thin on how to use it as described.

Am I trying to put a square peg in a round hole?  What I've tried so far results in 404's.  If possible, can someone recommend a setup, or where I could find more information? If this is an ambiguous/stupid/pointless question, please feel free to tell me why!  I don't get my internet feelings hurt - just want to figure out how to scale my setup...

I am thinking of an alternate approach where the websocket server ip address could be served up through js.  Does anyone have any experience with anything like this?  Bueller...

Answer (score 0):

It may be oversimplistic, but why not use dns load balancing? i.e. multiple ip addresses for same host, and client will automatically choice one at random.

Comment: That's basically the idea I am trying to achieve, but it seems that taking servers out of the pool, or directing on load factors involves additional setup or 3rd party services - still it might do.  Do you know why this seems so hard in Nginx?

Comment: I don't think this setup involves nginx at all: you want clients to connect directly to server, skipping proxy. 
So, it should look like client connecting to service.example.com, dns server returns one of "A" records with low TTL (e.g. 1 min), how it choices that record is up to dns server - random, round-robin, load based. Nginx? Nginx just serving content.

Comment: I understand that nginx isn't involved in a round robin DNS, but I am still curious if it could be used to redirect websocket straight to my back end in some sort of load-balancing arrangement. DNS load-balancing is a potential alternative, but one which has it's own different set of challenges, AFAIK.